# refresh auto search mvc on click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have created a autosearch using MVC 4. when i click on a item from the list it shows, but i have a button on which i want to get rid of so i can cancel that item and search again..

This is what i have, which is working:

cshtml page:

```
<form>
    <div id="lblCustomer" style="display: none;">
        <h3>Customer: <span></span>  </h3>
        <div><a class="" id="btnChangeCustomer">change</a></div>
        <div>
            <a class="btn1" href="" id="btnAddCustomer">Add</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Contacts" class="col-lg-5" style="display:block;"></div>
</form>
```

In the Controller i have this which makes the auto complete work:

```
public class AdminAjaxController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult CustomerSearchJson(string q)
    {
        var ctx = new CustomerPortalEntities();

        var result = ctx.vw_MIFCustomers.Where(w => w.Cust_Name.StartsWith(q) || w.Cust_Num.StartsWith(q))
            .Select(s => new { s.Cust_Name , s.Cust_Num})
            .OrderBy(o => o.Cust_Num).Take(20).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

so this is my change button which i want it to refresh, but i dont no how i can do this, any idea:

```
<div><a class="" id="btnChangeCustomer">change</a></div>
```

This is what i want to refresh:

```
 <div id="Contacts" class="col-lg-5" style="display:block;"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use html helper 'AjaxActionLink' to perform the desired operation, please take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/).

If only for refreshing purpose, you may use jquery ajax to achieve that.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("action", "controller")",
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    data: json,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        // bind the data to your control
    }
});
```

Comment: but i dont want to link it to a page, what i want is the #Contacts to refresh

Comment: You may consider using jquery ajax to get the data for refreshing. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: yeah thats what i want to use jquery but its implementing it in my code the problem

Comment: i am able to search using my search function. however once i have this, i want a button "cancel" to delete the search and show the text box to enter the search again. #Contacts this is my search box. i need this to refresh so i can enter something in.

Comment: This is where you can use the ajaxactionlink, the implementation will take the steps as,
1. Create a partial view which will have the dropdown with the associated model.
2. Initially in your main view, you will load the partial within a container which will be a div.
3. When any text is entered in search control you just visible the delete button (which will be ajax action link hidden on page load).
4. On clicking the delete button you just invoke the respective action method and reload the partial view which we created earlier with the new data into the container div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63876/discussion-between-m-ali-and-venkat).